# PyQt: How to reuse a method (def) in another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to ask how to reuse a method (def) from one class in another class.

In my following code, there is a method `def center` in the `class FirstWindow`. I want to reuse this `def center` in `class SecondWindow`, without pasting the same code in the `class SecondWindow` again.

I searched a lot, but could not find the answer. Could anybody please give me some help? Thanks!

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class FirstWindow(QWidget):
    close_signal = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        super(FirstWindow, self).__init__()

        self.btn = QToolButton(self)
        self.btn.setText("click")

        self.btn.clicked.connect(second.handle_click)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.hide)
        self.close_signal.connect(self.close)

        self.show()

        self.center()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.close_signal.emit()
        self.close()

    def center(self):   # Question: How to reuse this method in class SecondWindow? 
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

class SecondWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(200, 200)
        self.setStyleSheet("background: black")

    def handle_click(self):
        if not self.isVisible():
            self.show()

    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    second = SecondWindow()
    first = FirstWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want several widgets to share the same method, you can only do one function:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

def center(widget):
    qr = widget.frameGeometry()
    cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    widget.move(qr.topLeft())


class FirstWindow(QWidget):
    close_signal = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        super(FirstWindow, self).__init__()

        self.btn = QToolButton(self)
        self.btn.setText("click")

        self.btn.clicked.connect(second.handle_click)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.hide)
        self.close_signal.connect(self.close)

        self.show()
        center(self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.close_signal.emit()
        self.close()

class SecondWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(200, 200)
        self.setStyleSheet("background: black")
        center(self)

    def handle_click(self):
        if not self.isVisible():
            self.show()

    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    second = SecondWindow()
    first = FirstWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```